# possible missing library when running cmake

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I am trying to install a [program](https://code.google.com/p/mplabs/wiki/QuickInstall) on my machine (running Linux), but I get the following error when I run `make`:

```
Starting build...
Working Directory : /home/laptop/mplabs_test
Build Type        : 

Generating OMP binary...
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
make: *** [lbs3d] Error 2
```

What is wrong, am I missing a library?

Comment: You could also switch to [ninja](https://martine.github.io/ninja/): It is faster and it has less pitfalls than make. Cmake supports it. [Installing ninja](https://github.com/martine/ninja/releases) is super fast, it's just a matter of downloading an executable and putting it in your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Makefile uses bash specific syntax (`|&`) but the commands are executed by `/bin/sh`, which does not point to `/bin/bash`.

On my computer (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 16  2014 /bin/sh -> dash
```

A solution could be to let the symbolic link `/bin/sh` point to `/bin/bash`:

```
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Comment: Modifying random system paths like this is **never** a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the shell that make uses for executing recipes by setting the `SHELL` variable in the makefile.

If that makefile uses bash-specific features then it should be setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` already. Since it appears it isn't doing that you get to do that yourself instead.

Either modify the makefile in question or use

```
make SHELL=/bin/bash
```

instead of just running `make`.