# bash specific syntax of Makefile on Mac OS

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to get a program running on my Mac (Yosemite). It is the same program and the same problem discussed here:

[possible missing library when running cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793634/possible-missing-library-when-running-cmake)

The suggested solution does not work for me. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: If that solution doesn't work then it isn't the same problem. Post more details.

Comment: Good point. The solution presented is for an Ubuntu system. I wonder if it is because I am using a Mac that the solution doesn't work for me. I get the same error message though.

Comment: Doesn't osx run bash by default anyway ? What do you get if you type `echo $SHELL`

Comment: huh ?

Comment: it returns /bin/bash

Comment: That solution is a very bad one. You should **not** modify crucial system paths like that **ever**. I've added the correct solution to that question. Try setting `SHELL` inside make. make doesn't use the value of `SHELL` from its environment for safety.